# Usar paginação em 2 listas sem que uma influencie a outra

Tags: php, jquery, paginação

Estou listando imagens e características delas que são recolhidas da base-de-dados. Conforme pode ser visto em baixo, eu já estou listando as 2 imagens e suas características, cada imagem é de uma tabela na base-de-dados.

[image: Captura de Tela]

O problema que estou a ter é que quando eu clico para ir para próxima foto da "CHURRASQUEIRA DE INOX BAFO" a "CHURRASQUEIRA DE INOX" também muda.

**Código da paginação:**

```
$nr = mysql_num_rows($sql);

if (isset($_GET['pn'])) { 
$pn = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $_GET['pn']); 

} else { 
$pn = 1;
} 

$itemsPerPage = 1; 

$lastPage = ceil($nr / $itemsPerPage);


if ($pn < 1) { 
$pn = 1; 
} else if ($pn > $lastPage) { 
$pn = $lastPage; 
} 

$centerPages = "";
$sub1 = $pn - 1;
$sub2 = $pn - 2;
$add1 = $pn + 1;
$add2 = $pn + 2;
if ($pn == 1) {
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <span class="pagNumActive">' . $pn . '</span> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $add1 . '">' . $add1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
} else if ($pn == $lastPage) {
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $sub1 . '">' . $sub1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <span class="pagNumActive">' . $pn . '</span> &nbsp;';
} else if ($pn > 2 && $pn < ($lastPage - 1)) {
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $sub2 . '">' . $sub2 . '</a> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $sub1 . '">' . $sub1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <span class="pagNumActive">' . $pn . '</span> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $add1 . '">' . $add1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $add2 . '">' . $add2 . '</a> &nbsp;';
} else if ($pn > 1 && $pn < $lastPage) {
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $sub1 . '">' . $sub1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <span class="pagNumActive">' . $pn . '</span> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $add1 . '">' . $add1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
}
$limit = 'LIMIT ' .($pn - 1) * $itemsPerPage .',' .$itemsPerPage; 

$sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM churrasqueira_bafo ORDER BY id ASC $limit"); 

$paginationDisplay = "";

if ($lastPage != "1"){

    $paginationDisplay .= '';

    if ($pn != 1) {
        $previous = $pn - 1;
        $paginationDisplay .=  '&nbsp;  <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $previous . '"><i class="icon-arrow-left"></i></a> ';
    } 

    if ($pn != $lastPage) {
        $nextPage = $pn + 1;
        $paginationDisplay .=  '&nbsp;  <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $nextPage . '"><i class="icon-arrow-right"></i></a> ';
    } 
}
```

Esse código é para exibir a lista da churrasqueiras "BAFO". Ai eu tentei alterar o código só trocando a variável do `pagination`, que para mostrar a churrasqueira prática fica `paginationDisplay2`.

Comment: Dei um arranjo à tua pergunta, se alguma coisa perdeu o conceito original, por favor avisa-me ou reverte a edição.

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que dá para entender na tua pergunta, estás a utilizar o mesmo código para ambas as paginações, mas não estás a indicar em que lista é que o utilizador clicou para solicitar a alteração da imagem e características associadas.

Sem ver todo o teu código é difícil ser assertivo o suficiente para te apresentar uma solução a funcionar, mas em teoria, o que precisas fazer é adicionar um parâmetro em cada link que identifique a lista e um outro que te identifique o registo que está a ser apresentado.

Com esses parâmetros vais conseguir no lado do PHP saber qual das listas deve mudar e qual deve ficar como estava.

## Exemplo

Pegando nos links da tua paginação actual adicionamos ao endereço o seguinte:

- Parâmetro de URL `s` com o valor `1` ou `2` para identificar os sliders;
- Parâmetro de URL `a` com o ID do campo anterior para podermos apresentar o registo que estava a ser apresentado no slider que não foi "clicado".

Ilustração do novo URL com indicação do slider `s` e indicação do registo anterior `a`:

```
<!--                                  slider à esquerda      registo com ID 15            -->
<!--                                                 ↓        ↓                           -->
<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$add1.'&amp;s=1&amp;a=15"> </a>
```

No lado do PHP vamos verificar o slider clicado e para o slider não clicado vamos ver qual o registo que estava a ser apresentado:

**Exemplo de código para a paginação do slider #1**

```
// Se temos a variável de URL "s" e a mesma é o número 1
if (isset($_GET['s']) && is_numeric($_GET['s']) && $_GET['s']==1) {

  /* ir à base de dados recolher o
   * registo conforme estavas a fazer
   */


// se a variável de URL "s" não é 1, então é porque o utilizador
// clicou na paginação do slider #2 e para este slider devemos
// apresentar novamente o registo anterior que vem identificado
// na variável de URL "a"
} elseif (isset($_GET['a']) && is_numeric($_GET['a'])) {

  $apresentarRegistoComID = $_GET['a'];
  // consultar a base de dados para recolher o registo com o ID = "$apresentarRegistoComID"
}
```

Para o slider #2, é *copy&paste*, onde muda apenas o número do slider de `1` para `2`.

Comment: otima explicação, você tem skype?

Comment: me add no skype: felipe.planow